# How do I connect to and write a csv file to a remote instance of Databricks Apache Spark from Java?

Tags: java, apache-spark, databricks, databricks-connect

I'm trying to connect to a remote instance of Databricks and write a csv file to a specific folder of the DBFS.  I can find bits and pieces here and there but I'm not seeing how to get this done.  How do I add the file to DBFS on a remote Databricks instance from a Java program running on my local machine?

I'm currently using a community instance I created from here:
https://databricks.com/try-databricks

This is the url for my instance (I'm guessing the "o=7823909094774610" is identifying my instance).
https://community.cloud.databricks.com/?o=7823909094774610

Here's some of the resources I'm looking at trying to resolve this but I'm still not able to get off of the ground:

- The Databricks Connect documentation: This talks about connecting but
  not specifically from Java.  It gives and example of "connecting
  Eclipse" to data bricks that seems to be how to get the jar
  dependency for this (side question, is there a mvn version of this?).  https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-connect.html#run-examples-from-your-ide
- Some Java sample code: Doesn't seem to have an example of connecting
  to a remote Databricks instance
  https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
- Databricks File System (DBFS) Documentation: Gives a good overview of
  file functions but doesn't seem to talk specifically about how to
  connect from a remote Java application and write the file to the
  Databricks instance from the Java application
  https://docs.databricks.com/data/databricks-file-system.html
- FileStore documentation: Gives a good overview of file store but
  again doesn't seem to talk specifically about how to do this from a
  remote Java application
  https://docs.databricks.com/data/filestore.html

Comment: databricks connect isn't supported for community edition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a look at the [DBFS REST API](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/dbfs.html), and consider using that in your Java application.

If a Java solution is not required, then you could also take a look at the [databricks-cli](https://github.com/databricks/databricks-cli). After installing it with pip (`pip install databricks-cli`) you simply have to:

1. Configure the CLI by running: `databricks configure`

   - Host: https://community.cloud.databricks.com/?o=7823909094774610
   - Username: <your username>
   - Password: <your password>
2. Copy the file to DBFS by running: `databricks fs cp <source> dbfs:/<target>`

Comment: Thanks Bram, this is a great answer! I'm looking into the REST API now.  I'll let you know how it works out.